# Cyclical dependency Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I run into this problem a lot where I have a variable that's dependent on another variable and vice versa. And the Svelte compiler complains that it's a cyclical dependency.

So let's say we have 3 checkboxes and a 'none of the above' checkbox below it. If user clicks one of the three checkboxes, the 'none' checkbox needs to be *unchecked*. But if user has one or more checkboxes already checks and *then* clicks the 'none' checkbox, all previously checked checkboxes need to be cleared.

```
<script>    
    const options = ["1", "2", "3"]
    let selected = options.map(() => false)
    let none = false

    $: {
        if (selected.length > 0) {
            none = false
        }
    }

    $: {
        if (none) {
            selected = []
        }
    }
</script>

{#each options as opt, index}
    <div>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" bind:checked={selected[index]}/>
        {opt}
    </label>
    </div>
{/each}
<div>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" bind:checked={none}/>
        None of the above
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    Checked: {options.filter((o, i) => selected[i])}
</div>
```

pen: https://svelte.dev/repl/7d717ab296174f1b88847fb51628b901?version=3.38.3

Comment: You probably don't want to `bind:checked` for the `none` variable, `none` should be a computed property or just put the calculation in the `checked` attribute directly. You probably want to use `onchange` to set the selected options to be blank. You also have an issue where you're just creating a length 3 array `[false, false, false]`, you probably meant to filter or create an empty array and add indexes to it

Answer (score 0):

as @Samathingamajig said, I should not directly databind, but instead listen to the `on:change` events. Thanks